# how ios core location distance filter work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager

I am using a `CLLocationManager` to get the location data in my ios app, I am using `locationManager.distanceFilter` method to update how often I want to update my location.

Does this method record the location every time the device moves at least that much of distance? and what happens if it is set to 0? will it update the location even if the location is not changing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With the distance filter set to 0 you should get new location about every 1 second. All of them will be slightly different even if you are not moving because GPS/GLONASS accuracy is not perfect. If you set it to some bigger value next location will be reported only when the distance between locations will be greater than specified value.